# Creating Excel Files from given name list with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create excel files with the given set of names.

Given names stored in Names.xls at A1:A8 =

1. Wall -CMU
2. Wall - Painting
3. Wall - Exterior Siding
4. Wall - Insulation
5. Pipe - Copper
6. Pipe - Ductile Iron
7. Pipe - CPVC
8. Tank - Sodium Bisulphate

I want to create a new excel file, rename it based on the given name list, save and close it and then jump to next file.

The code below is only to create the first file:

```
Sub AddNewWorkbook1()
    'Adding New Workbook
    Workbooks.Add
    'Saving the Workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\goktem\Desktop\Change Orders\Wall - CMU.xls"
    Close
End Sub
```

I need to write a code to choose the filename from the given name list and create a loop.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to play with where the list is etc, but just create a simple loop.

```
Sub AddNewWorkbook1()
Dim wbName as String

'Adding New Workbook
    For i = 1 to 8
        wbName = Cells(i, 1).Value
        Workbooks.Add
'Saving the Workbook
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\goktem\Desktop\Change Orders\" & wbName & ".xls"
        Close
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim.

I have opened VBA in the excel file of name lists and run your code above and it created 8 excel files.